# Select another audio track

Tags: default, default-programs, video-player

How can I set another audio track in a movie (for default ubuntu video player)?

Usually, I can do this by: `View` --> `Languages` --> `Name of audio track`.

But when audio track is not inside video file, there is nothing like "select audio track in another place".

Comment: You could try VLC instead.

Answer (score 1):

use vlc:

- Go to Media -> Open Multiple Files....
- In the Open Media window, click Add....
- In the Select one or multiple files window, select the desired video file. Click Open.
- In the Open Media window, tick Show more options, then tick Play another media synchronously. Click Browse....
- In the second Open Media window, click Add....
- In the Select one or multiple files window, select the desired file that contains the audio which will be played on top of the video previously selected. (The file that contains the audio can be a video file.) Click Open.
- In the second Open Media window, click Select.
- In the first Open Media window, click Play.
- Go to Audio -> Audio track -> Track 2. (If you have more than one track available, pick the one that corresponds to the desired audio overlay.)